# create-react-app shows error and aborts installation

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

from last 4-5 hours suddenly my create-react-app stopped working it gives the following error

````
```

F:\Java Script\React apps>npx create-react-app portfolio

Creating a new React app in F:\Java Script\React apps\portfolio.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

yarn add v1.22.4
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/rxjs/-/rxjs-6.5.4.tgz: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "F:\\Java Script\\React apps\\portfolio\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...```

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts cra-template --cwd F:\Java Script\React apps\portfolio has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Done.
````

all of my node npm versions are up to date

Comment: my network connection is well and there is no problem with network connection

Comment: It may be due to a firewall or virus protection etc.

Comment: The problem is solved today I don't know how but I rember i reninstalled create-react-app.. But don't know the actual reason...